# Dot puzzle wrapped around a pillar near the end of The Witness

Tags: the-witness

Near the end of The Witness, there are a series of puzzles wrapped around pillars.

I'm having trouble with the one composed of a 6x5 grid mostly covered with dots ⬣. I've already tried drawing it on paper, but still couldn't figure it out. I need some hints.

```
              |  
--*--*--*--*--*--*--
  |  |  |  |     |
--*--*--*--*  *--*--
  |  |  |     |  |
--*--*--*  *--*--*--
  |  |     |  |  |
--*--*  *--*--*--*--
  |     |  |  |  |
--O--O--O--*--*--*--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no spoiler tags here because it doesn't work correctly with code blocks. So...

Spoiler warning! 3...

Spoiler warning! 2...

Spoiler warning! 1...

Since a dot requires a line passing through it, we can pick which dots have only two possible connections:

```
              |  
--*--*--*--*--*--*--
  |  |  |  |     |
--*--*--*--┛  ┏--*--
  |  |  |     |  |
--*--*--┛  ┏--*--*--
  |  |     |  |  |
--*--┛  ┏--*--*--*--
  |     |  |  |  |
--O--O--O--*--*--*--
```

Extending the lines from those six dots leads to four more dots being connected:

```
              |  
--*--*--*--*--*--*--
  |  |  |  ┃     |
--*--*--┏━━┛  ┏━━*--
  |  |  ┃     ┃  |
--*--┏━━┛  ┏━━┛--*--
  |  ┃     ┃  |  |
--*━━┛  ┏━━┛--*--*--
  |     ┃  |  |  |
--O--O--O--*--*--*--
```

Now, we can repeat the same idea and create two new corners based on the four dots we've just connected:

```
              |  
--*--*--*--*--*--*--
  |  ┃  |  ┃     |
--*━━┛--┏━━┛  ┏━━*--
  |  |  ┃     ┃  |
--*--┏━━┛  ┏━━┛--*--
  |  ┃     ┃  |  |
--*━━┛  ┏━━┛--┏━━*--
  |     ┃  |  ┃  |
--O--O--O--*--*--*--
```

This leads to two dots that can only be connected horizontally:

```
              |  
--*--┏━━━━━┓--*--*--
  |  ┃  |  ┃     |
--*━━┛--┏━━┛  ┏━━*--
  |  |  ┃     ┃  |
--*--┏━━┛  ┏━━┛--*--
  |  ┃     ┃  |  |
--*━━┛  ┏━━┛--┏━━*--
  |     ┃  |  ┃  |
--O--O--O━━━━━┛--*--
```

Which leads to three more corners:

```
              ┃  
━━┓--┏━━━━━┓--┗━━*━━
  ┃  ┃  |  ┃     |
--*━━┛--┏━━┛  ┏━━*--
  |  |  ┃     ┃  |
--*--┏━━┛  ┏━━┛--*--
  |  ┃     ┃  |  |
--*━━┛  ┏━━┛--┏━━*--
  |     ┃  |  ┃  ┃
━━O--O--O━━━━━┛--┗━━
```

Almost there, only two dots and two free ends are left:

```
              ┃  
━━┓--┏━━━━━┓--┗━━━━━
  ┃  ┃  |  ┃     |
--┗━━┛--┏━━┛  ┏━━*--
  |  |  ┃     ┃  |
--*--┏━━┛  ┏━━┛--*--
  |  ┃     ┃  |  |
--*━━┛  ┏━━┛--┏━━┓--
  |     ┃  |  ┃  ┃
━━O--O--O━━━━━┛--┗━━
```

Which finally leads to the solution:

```
              ┃  
━━┓--┏━━━━━┓--┗━━━━━
  ┃  ┃  |  ┃     |
--┗━━┛--┏━━┛  ┏━━┓--
  |  |  ┃     ┃  ┃
━━┓--┏━━┛  ┏━━┛--┗━━
  ┃  ┃     ┃  |  |
--┗━━┛  ┏━━┛--┏━━┓--
  |     ┃  |  ┃  ┃
━━O--O--O━━━━━┛--┗━━
```

So... Drawing this on the computer, using characters, worked better for me than drawing on a piece of paper.